# st_mode of a symlink has weird value

Tags: symlink, stat, bit-masks

I'm `stat()`'ing this symlink (on Kubuntu GNU/Linux 16.04), and am getting the weird value of 0100600 octal (33152 decimal). If I bitwise-and it with `S_IFMT` (which is 0170000 octal), I get 0600 octal. What does that mean? `stat.h` lists the following values:

```
/* File types.  */
#define __S_IFDIR   0040000 /* Directory.  */
#define __S_IFCHR   0020000 /* Character device.  */
#define __S_IFBLK   0060000 /* Block device.  */
#define __S_IFREG   0100000 /* Regular file.  */
#define __S_IFIFO   0010000 /* FIFO.  */
#define __S_IFLNK   0120000 /* Symbolic link.  */
#define __S_IFSOCK  0140000 /* Socket.  */
```

I'm expecting to see 0120000, not 0600 (all octal). What gives?

Comment: `stat` of a symlink returns the status of the target of the symlink, not the symlink itself. Your symlink apparently points to a regular file with permission rw-------. You might consider reading the man page for a syscall you use.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @dave_thompson_085's observation: Indeed, `stat()` follows symlinks; I should be calling [`lstat()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) - which does exactly the same thing, but doesn't follow the link.